# high div breaks sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm working on a site with a sticky footer. Recently I added a shopping cart preview functionality to the navigation. Basically on mouseover a div opens up to show the items inside the shopping cart. Nothing special actually.

The problem occurs first when the item list becomes very long. The div containing the items somehow breaks the sticky footer.

To demonstrate the behaviour I've made a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexxus/PMabQ).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id = "main">
    <div id = "navigation">
        navigation
        <div id = "cart">
            cart
            <div id = "cartItems">
                <p>item 1</p>
                <p>item 2</p>
                <p>item 3</p>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "content">content</div>
    <div id = "footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightpink;
}

#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}

#cart {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

#cartItems {
    display: none;
}
```

I hope, somebody can give me a hint. I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: +1 for well formed question with fiddle

Comment: What do mean by breaks the footer ? As I think you are saying lists go down to footer when list is long. So to fix this you can add z-index to #cart. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMabQ/19/)

Comment: Look at the scroll bar, the footer should be at the bottom of the page, not the bottom of the window.

Comment: do you use any server side language for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options here. Selection is up to you

1. Add higher z-index to option panel and make it to show top of the footer (**not good** because if the item list is too long then it will go down beyond the footer and after footer it will show some empty area).
2. Add `overflow:scroll` to the `main` div and allow item list to sink to the content (**not good**, If it is sink then user cannot see the content).
3. Specify a max height to the item list and make `overflow:scrool` (Quit ok, but user need to scrool along the way down)
4. Make item list multi-column and set some max height to item list (I think this method is acceptable) (look at amazon left side shop by department menu).
5. Use JqueryUI according to make short and categorize your item list (Not bad, but have some works to do). http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I like the ideas 3 and 4. Maybe I'll try them out. Thanks!

Comment: cheers! y don't u mark this as the answer and earn me some =)

Comment: Actually your answer was the right one for me, although the problem with the high div isn't 100% solved (see my comment to Sowmya's solution). In the end I took your suggestion nr. 4 (kind of ;)). I've limited the amount of the items in the preview and placed a button "View all xx items" underneath, which is linked to the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` from `#cart` and use `float:right`

And add `overflow:auto` to `#main` so that it increases according to    the cart items.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightpink;
    overflow:auto
}

#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
width: 900px;
height: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
background-color: yellowgreen;
```

}

```
#cart {
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
}

#cartItems {
    display: none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PMabQ/24/)**

Comment: This doesn't fix the footer not going to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @DanielImms Ya correct. Thanks for identifying that. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @Sowmya Your solution is almost right. The bottom piece of the #cartItems div appears behind the #footer. This would mean some of the last items will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated jsfiddle that makes the cart go over the footer - see if this is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/PMabQ/20/

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightpink;
}

#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: orange;
}

#content {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
    width: 900px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    z-index: 1;
}

#cart {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 2;
}

#cartItems {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look right for me using position: fixed on the #footer. I wonder, why the #main div is not being scaled to 100% height of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Change footer's position to `fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Change the overflow of your #main div:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Do not put your footer into your #main div

And that gives that :

http://jsfiddle.net/PMabQ/27/